# Java Non-Static Variable Referenced from Static Context Error

Tags: java, object, arraylist, static, non-static

I'd like to state that this question is very possibly a duplicate, but I'm not sure exactly what the issue is: I'm unable to do a proper search because of this.

I'm currently working on a painting program in Java. I'm trying to store the instructions for drawing the shapes in an ArrayList of Shape objects. I'm also using a MouseListener to get the coordinates.

The goal is that when the mouse is pressed, it keeps a record of that point. When it is released, it keeps record of that second point, then sends the two coordinates to the constructor, in the line history.add(new Shape(x, y, x2, y2)).

The relevant code is the following:

```
// Create an ArrayList for the History
static ArrayList history = new ArrayList(0);

.
.
.

// Co-ordinates for rectangle painting
static int x = 0;
static int y = 0;
static int x2 = 0;
static int y2 = 0;

.
.
.

/**
 * A class for handling mouse input
 * 
 * All methods within the MouseHandler class MUST be there
 * If not, the code will not compile.
 */
private static class MouseHandler implements MouseListener
{
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        x2 = e.getX();
        y2 = e.getY();

        //repaint() is a special method that must be called to "repaint"
        //your shapes on the screen. 
        canvas.repaint();
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // Create a new shape on the button unclick
        history.add(new Shape(x, y, x2, y2));
    }
}
```

This code throws an exception at the line history.add(new Shape(x, y, x2, y2)); : "Non-static method this cannot be referenced from a static context." The error seems to specifically reference (new Shape(x, y, x2, y2)). I don't understand why this method would be non-static.

Any help is greatly appreciated in advance,
Placowdepuss

Edit: Here is my full code:

```
//Import packages needed

// For the GUI
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*; 

// For the ArrayList
import java.util.*;

/**
* A simple drawing application.
* 
* @author (Massimo A. Lipari) 
* @version (1.0.0)
*/
public class PaintProgram
{
// Create the frame and the panels for the GUI
static JFrame frame = new JFrame("PaintIt");
static JPanel panel = new JPanel();
static JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
static MyPanel canvas = new MyPanel();

static JLabel sampleText = new JLabel("Label");

// Create an array for the buttons
static JButton[] buttonArray = new JButton[12];

// Create an ArrayList for the History
static ArrayList<Shape> history = new ArrayList<Shape>();

// Co-ordinates for rectangle painting
static int x, y, x2, y2;

// Create a variable for keeping track of the active tool
static String activeTool;

// Variables for holding the current colour and fill settings
static boolean currentFill;
static Color currentColour;

public static void main(String[] args)
{        
    // Set the frame size
    frame.setSize(1920,1040);

    // Create the mouse listeners
    canvas.addMouseListener(new MouseHandler());

    // Set the size for the canvas portion of the screen
    canvas.setSize(1920, 880);

    // Add panels to frame

    // Set layout for panel
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    createButtonPanel();
    panel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panel.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

    // Set frame to visible and allows it to exit on closing of the frame
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void createButtonPanel()
{
    // Set the buttonPanel size, and creates a grid layout for it
    buttonPanel.setSize(1920, 160);

    buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 12));

    // Initialize the buttons
    for (int i = 0; i < buttonArray.length; i++) {
        buttonArray[i] = new JButton("Button " + (i + 1));

        // Create and add a button handler
        buttonArray[i].addActionListener(new ButtonHandler());

        buttonArray[i].setIcon(new ImageIcon("icon" + i + ".png"));
        buttonArray[i].setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        buttonPanel.add(buttonArray[i]);
    }
}

/**
 * A class for handling button input (the tools) 
 */
private static class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getSource() == buttonArray[0]) {
            buttonArray[0].setBackground(JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "Choose a Color", sampleText.getForeground()));
        } else if (e.getSource() == buttonArray[1]) {
            currentFill = true;
            buttonArray[1].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            buttonArray[2].setBackground(null);
        } else if (e.getSource() == buttonArray[2]) {
            currentFill = false;
            buttonArray[1].setBackground(null);
            buttonArray[2].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        } else if (e.getSource() == buttonArray[3]) {
            activeTool = "paint";
        } else if (e.getSource() == buttonArray[4]) {
            activeTool = "rectangle";
        } else if (e.getSource() == buttonArray[5]) {
            activeTool = "triangle";
        } else if (e.getSource() == buttonArray[6]) {
            activeTool = "circle";
        } else if (e.getSource() == buttonArray[7]) {
            activeTool = "line";
        } else if (e.getSource() == buttonArray[8]) {
            activeTool = "text";
        } else if (e.getSource() == buttonArray[9]) {

        } else if (e.getSource() == buttonArray[10]) {

        } else if (e.getSource() == buttonArray[11]) {

        }
    }
}

/**
 * A class for handling mouse input
 * 
 * All methods within the MouseHandler class MUST be there
 * If not, the code will not compile.
 */
private static class MouseHandler implements MouseListener
{
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        x2 = e.getX();
        y2 = e.getY();

        //repaint() is a special method that must be called to "repaint"
        //your shapes on the screen. 
        canvas.repaint();
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // Create a new shape on the button unclick
        history.add(new Shape(x, y, x2, y2));
    }
}

/**
 * A class for painting the shapes
 */
private static class MyPanel extends JPanel
{
    public MyPanel() {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        setBackground(Color.white);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(600,600); 
    }

    // ALL drawing of shapes must be done in the paintComponent method
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);       

        //Drawing a basic rectangle from top left corner to bottom right on canvas
        if (x2 >= x && y2 >= y)
            g.drawRect(x, y, x2 - x, y2 - y);
        else if (x2 >= x && y2 <= y)
            g.drawRect(x, y2, x2 - x, y - y2);
        else if (x2 <= x && y2 >= y)
            g.drawRect(x2, y, x - x2, y2 - y);
        else if (x2 <= x && y2 <= y)
            g.drawRect(x2, y2, x - x2, y - y2);
    }
}

/**
 * A class that creates a colour picker
 * 
 * This code is the property of Oracle Systems Inc. It is copyrighted.
 */
static class ColorChooser_01 extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ColorChooser_01();
    }

    public ColorChooser_01() {
        this.setSize(300, 100);
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        sampleText.setBackground(null);
        panel1.add(sampleText);

        this.add(panel1);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Color c = JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "Choose a Color", sampleText.getForeground());
            if (c != null){
                sampleText.setForeground(c);
                buttonArray[0].setBackground(c);
            }
            else{
                sampleText.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * A class for creating objects of type Shape
 */
public class Shape
{
    // Variable for storing the type of shape
    String type;

    // Initialize variables for storing points for shape creation
    int xcoord;
    int ycoord;
    int xcoord2;
    int ycoord2;

    // Boolean variable to control whether the shape is filled or not -- defaults to false
    boolean fill = false;

    // Variable to hold the coulour
    Color colour;

    public Shape(int newX, int newY, int newX2, int newY2)
    {
        type = activeTool;

        xcoord = newX;
        ycoord = newY;
        xcoord2 = newX2;
        ycoord2 = newY2;

        fill = currentFill;
        colour = currentColour;
    }

    public String getType()
    {
        return type;
    }

    public int getX()
    {
        return xcoord;
    }

    public int getY()
    {
        return ycoord;
    }

    public int getX2()
    {
        return xcoord2;
    }

    public int getY2()
    {
        return ycoord2;
    }

    public boolean getFill()
    {
        return fill;
    }

    public Color getColour()
    {
        return colour;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why all your code is static.

Comment: Yeah why is your code static and shouldn't the declared variables be in the MouseHandler?

Comment: how `Shape` is defined?

Comment: The variables are used by other methods, both within the PaintProgram class and the classes within it (MouseHandler is one of which).

Comment: The code is mostly static because it is all being referenced from static contexts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the shape class to another file because you cannot have two public classes in the same file

Comment: Sorry if this wasn't clear, but the ArrayList is used by multiple classes. There is a main PaintProgram class, and MouseHandler is a class within it.

Also, for some reason this didn't solve the problem. I'll edit my post to show the whole code.

Comment: Then just reference it as `mouseHandlerInstance.history`

Comment: Same with the other vars

Comment: The error is not in reference to the ArrayList. It seems like it specifically has to do with the creating of a new object of type Shape.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code if that's the case.

Comment: Note that the shape class file has to be in its own class to be public.

Comment: Which is weird, because BlueJ gives me this error. I've never had an error like this before. It doesn't seem wrong to me either.

Comment: Try making the variables in the MouseHandler static and refer to it as MouseHandler.history

Comment: Even without referencing the history variable outside of the MouseHandler, it still gives me the error if I reference it inside of the MouseHandler.

Comment: Yeah than you need to move the shape class to a separate file most probably

Comment: Damn it, I went to sleep on it.I thought of it right as I got up. If I move the Shape class outside of the PaintProgram class, it should work fine. I'll try it later when I'm at my computer. Thanks.